# Inserting Content Notes as Experience(Community) user in test class fails

Tags: apex, community, contentnote

Getting an error trying to insert a ContentNote in a test class as a community user:

```
insert new ContentNote(Title = 'Cancellation evidence',
                        Content = Blob.valueOf(body));
```

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have the
> level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
> Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
> is necessary.: [NetworkId]

Looking at the doco there is no NetworkId field on the ContentNote - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm

Here is an example test method that fails, not including the setupLicenceCommunityUser method - that simply creates an account and a user for that account to one of our community profiles.

```
@IsTest
static void testContentNoteCommunityUser() {
    User communityUser = setupLicencedCommunityUser();

    System.runAs(communityUser) {
        insert new ContentNote(
            Title = 'Declaration Completed',
            Content = Blob.valueOf('')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating `ContentNote`, the workaround is to create `ContentVersion` record by setting field `PathOnClient` in the format `<your file title>.snote` (where suffix `.snote` determines that `ContentVersion` is of type note) and set the `NetworkId` to prevent the error message.

Inserting the `ContentVersion` auto-creates the contentnote record even in test class.

(Optionally) if you need to relate the content note to a specific custom or standard object record id, then insert `ContentDocumentLink` and set the `LinkedEntityId`.

```
@IsTest
static void testContentNoteCommunityUser() {
    User communityUser = setupLicencedCommunityUser();
    Id networkid = [SELECT Id from Network where name = 'Your Community Name'].Id;

    System.runAs(communityUser) {
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.title = 'Content version note';      
        cv.VersionData =Blob.valueOf('Test Content'); 
        cv.PathOnClient= 'Content verison note.snote'; //<your file title>.snote 
        cv.NetworkId= networkid ;
        insert cv; //auto creates the ContentNote record

        //optional 
        ContentVersion cvIns = [SELECT Id, OwnerId,ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where Id=:cv.Id];

        ContentDocumentLink contentDocLink1 = new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentDocLink1.LinkedEntityId = <related object recordid>;
        contentDocLink1.ContentDocumentId = cvIns.ContentDocumentId;
        contentDocLink1.shareType = 'V';
        contentDocLink1.visibility = 'AllUsers';
        insert contentDocLink1;

        //continue test logic and add asserts
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite having implemented this, I still encounter the same error message. Is there any other permission I need to enable?

Comment: @Damecek are you linking the content note with a record? If yes make sure the testing user has access to the record

Comment: I am getting the error when inserting the ContentVersion

Comment: @Damecek It's better to ask a new question so that you can provide your own code snippet. you can link your question with this question so that the community has maximum info to be able to help you